# RestKit session management

Tags: ios, restkit

What is the correct way of making "persistent" session with RestKit?

The most simple way is to make long session at the server side, but 
not sure it's safe for browser version. I prefer to implicitly re- 
login if session is expired, but in this case I have to handle session 
expiration, send new login request, receive response and than send 
again a target request. Sources become more complicated.

Is there any features in the RestKit which allows manage that 
automatically? Maybe just keep persistent session for iPhone app and 
short one for web version using features of CakePHP?

Thanks, 
Victor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want the session in order to for authentication/authorization to work?

I'm currently working on a RestKit project on iOS. For my needs, what I did was very close to the discussionboard example by RestKit's creators.

in iOS, you can write a `uniqueSecurityToken` to `NSUserDefaults`. It can be a property model of your user model on the iOS app. On Rails (Im making an assumption), if you have a auth gem like Authlogic/Sorcery, it's very easy to either override the `current_user` method or assigning one based on token.

For example,

```
def user_access_token 
    request.headers["HTTP_X_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN"] || request.headers["HTTP_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN"]
end

def check_for_mobile_token
    if token = user_access_token
      current_user = User.find_by_remember_me_token(token) || current_user
    end
  end
```

You can call a `before filter` to make sure that the authentication is always checked. on the IOS side, tell RestKit to send the uniqueSecurityToken as `HTTP_USER_ACCESS_TOKEN` in the headers. Note that this is probably not the most secure method, you should at least have HTTPS so that the transport is encrypted.

Here's the RestKit Discussion Board Project (very useful for RestKit/IOS)
https://github.com/RestKit/RKDiscussionBoard

Here's a Rails Presentation that outlines Rails/iOS integration 
http://www.slideshare.net/maximeguilbot/rails-as-ios-application-backend

If you're using another REST framework other than Rails, you can reference the JSON techniques too.

Comment: thanks. The RKDiscussionBoard project does not seem to have been updated for a while and does not work with the latest RestKit :(

Comment: Can still reference the methods in the User model I guess. I'm using an API key/secret combination but mainly still using the Rkboard technique. post cred + device_token from Button Tap in App => get API key/secret from server and store it in NSUserDefaults...

Comment: Thanks @daenibsy. I also have a free trial mechanism that expires, and then the person needs to get a paid account. I am not sure how to expire the token once the user is logged in to the app.

Comment: You can do it on the Rails side by setting a token_expires_at field I guess. Then you can probably choose to check and nil expired tokens any user logs in (performance) or do a 1 time expense daily by running a background job? Map the nil response from the server back to your iOS user model to trigger a login action? cheers =)

Comment: Thanks daemonsy! That makes sense on the Rails side. But on the iOS side, is there a way to run a background job? Or is there a way to expire the NSUserDefault token?

Comment: Maybe you can create a `[currentUser checkIfTokenExpired]` method and call them in the appropriate `viewDidLoad` or app delegate methods? Then direct them to your sign in view or gray out certain access areas?

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you'll want to do is develop a "[RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)" API that your app will use to talk to your server. A REST API, basically, lets the client send up all information that is needed to build state on the server. You shouldn't need to deal with sessions on the server for the iOS app.

The basic idea is that you can get some sort of auth token from the server when you log in. Then you can send that up with every request as a way of identifying the logged in user to your server.

Comment: Actually we already developed and published the application. Session management works fine. But how deal with session expiration? Make them pretty long or somehow to renew them? For example iPhone user may not use application for a week...

Comment: Can you set a longer cookie expiration date on the server side? When a user signs in, you renew the cookie? The users should have an explicit interface off the iphone to invalidate the cookies too? 

Would like to know you implemented the session, Victor.